# Node.js how to know when all async functions are done?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

This is my function:

```
var Tick = () => {
    binance.prices((error, ticker) => {
        for (var key in ticker) {
            if(key.includes('BTC')) {
                // Cryptocurrency can be bought with BTC
                var currency = {
                    price: ticker[key],
                    symbol: key
                }
                tickerModule.getOne(currency, function(err, rows) {
                    if (err) return console.log(err);
                });
            }
        }
        console.log('done?');
    });
}
```

I would expect that the console.log would execute after the async function inside but unfortunatly this isn't the case. How can I know when all async functions inside this function are done?

I've been struggling with this issue for a few days now, I hope someone can help me out with this.

Edit: I know I can use the callback function that gets triggered after the tickerModule.getOne however I want to know when all the async functions are done, not when 1 of them is done.

Comment: Use `Promise.all`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var Tick = () => {
    binance.prices((error, ticker) => {
        const promises = [];
        for (var key in ticker) {
            if (key.includes('BTC')) {
                // Cryptocurrency can be bought with BTC
                var currency = {
                    price: ticker[key],
                    symbol: key
                }
                promises.push(
                    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                        tickerModule.getOne(currency, function (err, rows) {
                            if (err) reject(err);
                            else resolve();
                        });
                    })
                );
            }
        }
        Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
            console.log('done?');
        }).catch(err => console.log(err));
    });
}
```

Uses a simple `Promise.all` to know when all the async calls are complete.

Comment: Thanks for your answer however when I log the promises before the promise.all(promises) then are all still <pending> and then console.log message inside never gets executed. The callback function in tickermodule.getOne is definitely triggered I get a response if I console.log in there.

Comment: You have to log inside `Promise.all`

Comment: Yeah I get that, I copied exactly what you have however the console.log inside the promise.all is never triggered. I think this is because when the Promise.all line is executed the status of the promises are still pending and it never checks again.

Comment: Ah shit it did work. Thanks. I just didn't execute the callback in some cases so it never completed the promise.